# List settings validation formula syntax

Tags: validation

I have two columns within a custom list which are check boxes (yes/no). I need to ensure either one of those check boxes are selected so trying to utilize sharepoint validation settings. It seems like a simple formula but it is not working for me, please help me with this syntax.
=IF([checkbox1]='false')AND([checkbox2]='false')  --- this returns syntax error

Thanks

Comment: It was my understanding that column validation could not reference other columns

Comment: At list settings level, under validation settings, we can refer any of the columns within that list right? i am trying to put the syntax over there to make sure at least one of those check boxes are selected.

Comment: Ah yes, you can do that at the list level, for some reason I was assuming you were trying at the column level. I don't think you can use the And operator.

Answer (score 4):

At least one can be selected:

```
=OR([checkbox1],[checkbox2])
```

Both must be selected:

```
=AND([checkbox1],[checkbox2])
```

Only one can be selected:

```
=AND(OR([checkbox1],[checkbox2]),NOT(AND([checkbox1],[checkbox2])))
```